# Can't find smbfs package in Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian

In squeeze there was a package `smbfs` for mounting samba filesystems. In wheezy this is no longer present. What is the new package name? Is there a general formula to solve problems like this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The package is called [`cifs-utils`](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/cifs-utils), it provides `mount.cifs` instead of `mount.smbfs`.

Answer (score 3):

In the previous release (squeeze), [smbfs](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/smbfs) is a compatibility package that exists only to depend on [cifs-utils](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/cifs-utils). So look for a `cifs-utils` package.